# i want to replace the node value in my XML

Tags: php, xml

This is my xml code.
I want to replace value of End,
for example, i.e, End = 'enddate'   ;
                  End = 'somedate' ;

Please help

```
<SailingDateRange MaxDuration="P07D" MinDuration="P07D" End="enddate" Start="startdate"></SailingDateRange>
```

I also tried the below code

```
$sail_dat_to = $_GET['date'];
$xml->SailingDateRange->End = $sail_dat_to;
```

But it adding a new line rather than replace the value.
pLease help

Comment: Pls use relevant tags only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341904/how-to-change-attribute-on-a-simplexml-element

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DanMiller but i don't  want to append new value i want to replace with new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xml->SailingDateRange['End'] = 'somedate';
$xml->asXml('file.xml');
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php